# Вынести переменные в метод

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как в даном примере

```
  if (mode === 'day') {
    return {
      title: date.format('dddd')
    }
  } else if (mode === 'week') {
    var momentArgument = (mode === 'week' ? 'isoWeek' : mode)
    var lineDate = getLineDate(date, momentArgument);
    var lineHeight = 90;
    var clientValue = lineHeight * clients.length;
    return {
      title: date.startOf(momentArgument).format('MMM') + ' ' + date.startOf(momentArgument).format('DD') + '-' + date.endOf(momentArgument).format('DD'),
      subtitle: 'Week ' + date.week(),
      isLine: lineDate.isLine,
      lineLeft: lineDate.lineLeft,
      lineHeight: clientValue + 'px'
    }
  } else if (mode === 'month') {
    var lineDate = getLineDate(date, mode);
    var lineHeight = 90;
    var clientValue = lineHeight * clients.length;
    return {
      title: date.format('MMMM'),
      daysInMonth: moment(date.format('YYYY-MM')).daysInMonth(),
      isLine: lineDate.isLine,
      lineLeft: lineDate.lineLeft,
      lineHeight: clientValue + 'px'
    }
  }
```

вынести строчки

```
var lineDate = getLineDate(date, mode);
var lineHeight = 90;
var clientValue = lineHeight * clients.length;
```

в отдельный метод

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться: зачем? и что вам мешается сделать `function aaa () { // блок кода }`?

Comment: что этот метод по-вашей логике должен делать? Ведь `lineDate` в нём не будет ни на что влиять. выделение метода ради метода?

Comment: @СергейМишин эти строчки повторяются дважды и выполняют одну и туже функцию, так что если у еня будет еще 20 `else if (mode === 'month')` то я повторять буду еще 20раз этот кусок кода ибо он там тоже будет.
20 конечно вряд ли, но просто это полезная практика

Comment: @DonnieDarko только для начала надо лично для себя понять: что именно должна делать эта функция. Пока, банальное выделение представленных ТРЁХ строчек кода в отдельную функцию выглядит бессмысленным. Тут нужно делать функцию именно под целый блок